# How I can evaluate $\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} xy(\frac{1+xy}{x^3+y^3})^{1/3}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus

I don't have idea how I can evaluate this double limit 
$$\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} xy \left(\frac{1+xy}{x^3+y^3} \right) ^{1/3}$$ could you help me please!

---

I try prove that $f$ is continuous: $f(x,y)=xy \left(\frac{1+xy}{x^3+y^3} \right) ^{1/3}$ if $x\not=-y$ and $f(x,y)=0$ if $x=-y$

Comment: Have you tried to rearrange the expression?

Comment: The function is not even defined in a whole neighborhood of $(0,0)$, since along $x+y=0$ the denominator vanishes identically.

Comment: Sorry, I complete the problem: you have that $f(x,y)=xy \left(\frac{1+xy}{x^3+y^3} \right) ^{1/3}$ if $x=-y$ and $f(x,y)=0$ if $x=-y$ I have tried all I know u.u

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: replace $1+xy$ by $1$ in the numerator (why?) and reduce to
$$
\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \left( \frac{x^3 y^3}{x^3+y^3} \right)^{1/3}.
$$
Put $\alpha =x^3$, $\beta=y^3$ and consider the constraint $\alpha + \beta = \alpha^3$ with $\alpha \to 0$. Then
$$
\frac{\alpha \beta}{\alpha+\beta} = \frac{\alpha^4-\alpha^2}{\alpha^3}
$$
which becomes unbounded as $\alpha \to 0$.

Comment: $1+xy$ by $1$? I would understand that if it was $1+x^2y^2$ but $1+xy$?

Comment: $xy \to 0$ as $(x,y) \to (0,0)$, I am trying to use a first order expansion. Let me say that the same "curve" should work even if you do not discard that term.

Comment: But you are working with a one variable so $lim_{x \rightarrow0}\frac{x^4-x^2}{x^3}$ not exist because $lim_{x\rightarrow0^{-}}\frac{x^4-x^2}{x^3}=\infty$ and  $lim_{x\rightarrow0^{+}}\frac{x^4-x^2}{x^3}=-\infty$

Comment: @Willyf Yes, that's exactly the spirit of constraining the function to a curve.

Comment: So the function is not continuous! thanksssss a lott

Comment: why $\alpha+\beta=\alpha^3$?

Comment: The line $\alpha+\beta=0$ is suspected to bring some singularity in the function. I just tried to "parametrize" a neighborhood of that straight line with smaller and smaller size.

Answer (score 0):

This is prossible?

$ 0\leq|xy\left(\frac{1+xy}{x^3+y^3}\right)^{1/3}|=|\left(\frac{x^3y^3+x^4y^4}{x^3+y^3}\right)^{1/3}|=|\left(\frac{x^3y^3}{x^3+y^3}+\frac{x^3y^3(xy)}{x^3+y^3}\right)^{1/3}|=|\left(\frac{x^3}{x^3+y^3}y^3+\frac{x^3}{x^3+y^3}y^3(xy)\right)^{1/3}|\leq|(y^3+y^3(xy))^{1/3}|\leq (y^2|y|+y^4|x|)^{1/3}\leq(|y|+|x|)^{1/3}$

so like the function is bounded by two function whose limits tends to $0$ then $f(x,y)$ tends to $0$¿?

Comment: The $=|\left(\frac{x^3}{x^3+y^3}y^3+\frac{x^3}{x^3+y^3}y^3(xy)\right)^{1/3}|\leq|y^3+y^3(xy)|$ step doesn't work when $x,y$ are of opposite signs (because the exponent of 3 is not even).

Answer (score 0):

In any neighborhood of $(0,0)$ there is a point of the form $(a,-a)$ with $0<a<1.$ Think of what happens as we approach $(a,-a)$ from the right. We have

$$f(a+h,-a) =   [\dots ]\cdot \left ( \frac{1}{(a+h)^3 +(-a)^3}\right)^{1/3},$$

where the expression in brackets has a nonzero limit as $h\to 0^+.$ But the other factor looks like $1/0^+$ as $h\to 0^+.$ It follows that $f$ is unbounded in any neighborhood of $(0,0),$ and so it's not even close: the limit in question doesn't exist, bigtime.

Answer (score -1):

Try Polar coordinates maybe $x=r \cos \phi$ and $y=r \sin \phi$ and then check the limit $r \to 0$.

Comment: This cannot be accepted as an answer. If you had tried, you would have realized that polar coordinates do not give a straightforward answer in this case. Maybe you could share your complete solution with us.

Comment: $$ xy (\frac{1+xy}{x^3 + y^3})^{1/3} = r^2 \cos \phi \sin \phi (\frac{1 + r^2 s cos \phi sin \phi}{r^3 \cos^3 \phi + r^3 \sin^3 \phi})^{1/3} = r \cos \phi \sin \phi  ( \frac{1 + r^2 sin \phi cos \phi}{ cos^3 \phi + sin^3 \phi})^{1/3} $$ which converges to 0 for $r \to 0$if the nominator is not equal to 0 ($x \ne -y$. Since $phi$ is arbitrary apart from this this gives you all ways to 0.

Comment: The last term containing $\phi$ is not bounded, if I am right... It diverges as $\phi \to 3\pi/4$.

Comment: yes the function diverges there so it is not continuous when setter 0 on $x = -y$

Comment: But everything is multiplied by $r \to 0$. I think it is a little harder than this.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @vonbrand: This (together with the comments) *is* an answer to the question. A poor one, I agree, but technically it is an answer. When deleting an answer, we should not judge it by its mathematical soundness.